# JQuery keyup prevents text selecion in Chrome. How to solve?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, onkeyup

I have a function that transforms the text to uppercase on `keyup`. The code looks like this (I think I found it on SO too):

```
$(selector).bind('keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) {
    var newKey = e.which - 32;
    e.keyCode = newKey;
    e.charCode = newKey;
  }
  $(this).val((object.val()).toUpperCase());
});
```

**The problem**

In Chrome, when I type some text and then try to select it using `shift` + `home`, the cursor goes back to the last char, not selecting anything.

I also tested in Firefox and IE and it's working ok.

Please help me

Comment: Hi! A jsFiddle would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of possible solutions is not changing value on every keyup, but just when the value actually changes:

```
$('#input').bind('keyup', function(e) {

    if (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) {
        var newKey = e.which - 32;
        e.keyCode = newKey;
        e.charCode = newKey;
    }

    var oldVal = $(this).val();
    var newVal = oldVal.toUpperCase();

    if(oldVal != newVal)
    {
        $(this).val(newVal);
    }

});​
```

See it in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Nh7EL/).

Comment: Sometimes the you got blind and don't think simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice solution using only css here:

http://jsfiddle.net/46jrg/

just apply

```
text-transform: uppercase
```

to the text input region, and then you don't have to worry about that complicated javascript stuff. Less code means less bugs! :)

EDIT: When you select and copy the text, it will still be capitalized, but if you're submitting it to a server, you will have to either upcase it before send or upcase it when it gets there. This is normally no big deal though. Most common server-side languages can do it in a single method call.

Java has `String::toUpperCase`

PHP has the `strtoupper` function

Python has `String::upper`

Ruby has `String::upcase`

Perl has the `uc` function

Javascript has `String::toUpperCase`

C#.NET / VB.NET has `String::ToUpper`

Comment: Last time I tried this, on an input form it doesn't change the value that is being submitted. It is used for display only.

Comment: Agreed, though the OP just wanted to be able to select the capitalized text. I'll update my answer though. :)

Comment: Surely you can just do a `.ToUpper()` (language dependant) or similar in the part where you're sending the data?

Comment: @RemarkLima yeah, you're right. I edited my answer to include a handful of easy ways to deal with this.

Comment: And C#.NET / VB.NET is `"str".ToUpper()`